# web page title change

Tags: c#, jquery, checkbox

I am doing some changes to our website and have just added a checkbox list which works great but I need the title of the page to change when I select more than one checkbox.
Currently if nothing is selected it says “Summary for ….” Then when you select a check box it says “Summary for ….(name of checkbox)”
When more than one checkbox is selected I need it to say “Summary for ….(multi)”
I have found this code in the aspx.cs:

```
public partial class _default : PortalReportPage
{
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedRegions { get; set; }
    public GroupStatisticCollection Stats { get; set; }
    public CompanyRegionCollection Regions { get; set; }
    public int PropertyCount { get; set; }

    protected override void BindPath()
    {
        PagePath = PortalPath.GetBasicPath();
        PagePath.AddNode(Container.Name, "~/company/default.aspx?id=" + Container.NodeId);
        PagePath.AddNode("Reports", "~/company/reports.aspx?id=" + Container.NodeId);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get all Selected regions into the SelectedRegions variable...
        SelectedRegions = GetArrayFromQueryString<Int32>("region").ToList();

        // TODO: remove this when the sole RegionId is ready to be replaced by the SelectedRegions list
        if (SelectedRegions.Count > 0)
        {
            RegionId = SelectedRegions.First();
        }
        else
        {
            RegionId = 0;
        }

        GetStatistics();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.Regions = CompanyRegionCollection.GetRegions(Container.NodeId);

            if (this.Regions != null && this.Regions.Count > 0)
            {
                if (this.RegionId == 0)
                {
                    this.PropertyCount = Regions.Sum(r => r.PropertyCount);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.Regions.Any(r => r.NodeId == RegionId))
                    {
                        this.PropertyCount = Regions.First(r => r.NodeId == RegionId).PropertyCount;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (this.PropertyCount == 0)
            {
                if (this.Regions.Count == 0)
                {
                    this.PropertyCount = PropertyList.GetProperties(PropertyCriteria.NewCriteria(Container.NodeId, PropertyCriteriaSubject.Company)).TotalRecords;
                }
            }

            BindOptionsPanel();
        }

        this.Title = "Summary for " + Container.Name;

        if (RegionId != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Title += string.Format(" ({0})", NodeBasic.GetNodeBasic(RegionId).Name);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private void GetStatistics()
    {
        Stats = GroupStatisticCollection.GetCategoryStatistics(Container.NodeId, SelectedRegions);
    }

    private void BindOptionsPanel()
    {
        RegionsChecklist.Items.Add(new ListItem(" All", "0"));

        foreach (var region in Regions.OrderBy(r => r.Name))
        {
            var item = new ListItem(region.Name, region.NodeId.ToString());

            if (SelectedRegions.Contains(region.NodeId))
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }

            RegionsChecklist.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    protected void ExportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExportToCsv(this.Stats, this.Title);
    }

    protected void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = "~/reports/compliance/default.aspx?id=" + Container.NodeId;

        string selectedRegionString = "";

        foreach (ListItem item in RegionsChecklist.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                selectedRegionString = selectedRegionString + item.Value + ",";
            }
        }

        url += "&region=" + selectedRegionString.TrimEnd(','); 
        Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl(url));
    }
```

But I am not sure what I need to change and if I am looking in the right place?
Can anyone offer any advice on it please?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: When more then one checkbox is checked I need the title to change to say "Summary for.... (Multi)" instead of just the container name, not sure what to change in the code to make that happen? I looked at Catch exceptions but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You will have to create a string for all the checked checkboxes and assign them to Title.

Comment: Also if you are doing this in code behind you will have to postback..

Comment: Thank you. Still fairly new to dev so any help and advice is greatly appreciated. I will have a play and see if I can get it working. Thanks again.

Comment: Post the code so that we will be able to provide help... 1) Where the above code is actually written (in which function)?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question to show all of the code in the function.

Comment: Added one client side answer. Do you strictly want it to be server side?

Comment: If you can supply the server side as well it would be great to see and will help me learn. Thank you.

Comment: your try catch isn't much use because you don't reveal the exception. Try `catch (Exception ex`)` and then put a breakpoint over it, you'll be able to view the contents of `ex` in the debugger and see the message. You could also log the exception to a file or the windows event log for future reference.

Comment: Thank you for that I will have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used what was provided to me in the answer above and managed to put together the below code snippet that works a treat.

this.Title = "Summary for " + Container.Name;

```
        if (SelectedRegions.Count > 1)
        {
            RegionId = SelectedRegions.First();
            this.Title = "Summary for " + Container.Name + " (Multiple Regions)";
        }
        else if (SelectedRegions.Count > 0)
        {
            RegionId = SelectedRegions.First();
            this.Title += string.Format(" ({0})", NodeBasic.GetNodeBasic(RegionId).Name);
        }
        else
        {
            RegionId = 0;
            this.Title = "Summary for " + Container.Name;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling this at client side would be a good idea.

Try following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            $(document).attr("title", $(this).next().text());
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        }
    });
});
```

This will change the title of your page to the selected checkbox's "Text" property.

Make sure, you have not set AutoPostBack="True".

**UPDATE - For Server Side**

For handling it on server side, set the AutoPostBack = "true"

Then in code behind try following

```
 string sTitle = "";

            if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                sTitle += CheckBox1.Text + " ";
            }
            if (CheckBox2.Checked)
            {
                sTitle += CheckBox2.Text + " ";
            }

            this.Title = sTitle;
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I have managed to take what you provided me and use it for what I need to make it work. Its nice to know as a beginner I can come here and get some helpful hints.